# Could you give me any clue Why 'Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext'?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

When I put the 'val lines = sc.textFile("hdfs:///input")' in yarn-client,  'Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext' error occur. I searched all day long for two days, but I don't know where is cause. "hdfs:///input" is right, because when I executed it in standalone mode, I worked well.

Could you give me a any idea of that?
I'm using spark 1.5.2, hadoop 2.7.2.

```
tarting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /opt/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6/sbin/../logs/spark-root-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-master.out
192.168.111.203: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /opt/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6/sbin/../logs/spark-root-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-slave2.out
192.168.111.202: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /opt/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6/sbin/../logs/spark-root-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-slave1.out
[root@master spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6]# bin/spark-shell --master yarn-client
16/03/19 05:59:12 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/03/19 05:59:12 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
16/03/19 05:59:12 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
16/03/19 05:59:12 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(root); users with modify permissions: Set(root)
16/03/19 05:59:13 INFO spark.HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
16/03/19 05:59:13 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
16/03/19 05:59:13 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:46780
16/03/19 05:59:13 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP class server' on port 46780.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.5.2
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_73)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
16/03/19 05:59:17 INFO spark.SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.5.2
16/03/19 05:59:17 WARN spark.SparkConf: 
SPARK_JAVA_OPTS was detected (set to '-Dspark.driver.port=53411').
This is deprecated in Spark 1.0+.

Please instead use:
 - ./spark-submit with conf/spark-defaults.conf to set defaults for an application
 - ./spark-submit with --driver-java-options to set -X options for a driver
 - spark.executor.extraJavaOptions to set -X options for executors
 - SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS to set java options for standalone daemons (master or worker)

16/03/19 05:59:17 WARN spark.SparkConf: Setting 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions' to '-Dspark.driver.port=53411' as a work-around.
16/03/19 05:59:17 WARN spark.SparkConf: Setting 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions' to '-Dspark.driver.port=53411' as a work-around.
16/03/19 05:59:17 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
16/03/19 05:59:17 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
16/03/19 05:59:17 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(root); users with modify permissions: Set(root)
16/03/19 05:59:18 INFO slf4j.Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
16/03/19 05:59:18 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
16/03/19 05:59:18 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.111.201:53411]
16/03/19 05:59:18 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 53411.
16/03/19 05:59:18 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
16/03/19 05:59:18 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
16/03/19 05:59:18 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-f70b1bb6-288b-4894-bb49-22d1fc3d8d89
16/03/19 05:59:18 INFO storage.MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 534.5 MB
16/03/19 05:59:18 INFO spark.HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /tmp/spark-58591b6b-5b19-4bc0-a993-0b846de5ef6f/httpd-fe0c46a2-1d87-4bc7-8b4f-adfc79cb762a
16/03/19 05:59:18 INFO spark.HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
16/03/19 05:59:18 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
16/03/19 05:59:18 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:40258
16/03/19 05:59:18 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 40258.
16/03/19 05:59:18 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/03/19 05:59:18 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
16/03/19 05:59:18 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040
16/03/19 05:59:18 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
16/03/19 05:59:18 INFO ui.SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://192.168.111.201:4040
16/03/19 05:59:19 WARN metrics.MetricsSystem: Using default name DAGScheduler for source because spark.app.id is not set.
16/03/19 05:59:19 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /192.168.111.201:8032
16/03/19 05:59:19 INFO yarn.Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 2 NodeManagers
16/03/19 05:59:19 INFO yarn.Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (8192 MB per container)
16/03/19 05:59:19 INFO yarn.Client: Will allocate AM container, with 896 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
16/03/19 05:59:19 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
16/03/19 05:59:19 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
16/03/19 05:59:19 INFO yarn.Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
16/03/19 05:59:21 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/opt/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.5.2-hadoop2.6.0.jar -> hdfs://192.168.111.201:9000/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1458334003417_0002/spark-assembly-1.5.2-hadoop2.6.0.jar
16/03/19 05:59:25 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/spark-58591b6b-5b19-4bc0-a993-0b846de5ef6f/__spark_conf__2052137095112870542.zip -> hdfs://192.168.111.201:9000/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1458334003417_0002/__spark_conf__2052137095112870542.zip
16/03/19 05:59:25 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
16/03/19 05:59:25 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
16/03/19 05:59:25 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(root); users with modify permissions: Set(root)
16/03/19 05:59:25 INFO yarn.Client: Submitting application 2 to ResourceManager
16/03/19 05:59:25 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1458334003417_0002
16/03/19 05:59:26 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1458334003417_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/03/19 05:59:26 INFO yarn.Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1458334765746
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1458334003417_0002/
     user: root
16/03/19 05:59:27 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1458334003417_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/03/19 05:59:28 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1458334003417_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/03/19 05:59:29 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1458334003417_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/03/19 05:59:30 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1458334003417_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/03/19 05:59:31 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1458334003417_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/03/19 05:59:32 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1458334003417_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/03/19 05:59:33 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1458334003417_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/03/19 05:59:34 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1458334003417_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/03/19 05:59:35 INFO cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster registered as AkkaRpcEndpointRef(Actor[akka.tcp://sparkYarnAM@192.168.111.203:46505/user/YarnAM#149895142])
16/03/19 05:59:35 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Add WebUI Filter. org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter, Map(PROXY_HOSTS -> master, PROXY_URI_BASES -> http://master:8088/proxy/application_1458334003417_0002), /proxy/application_1458334003417_0002
16/03/19 05:59:35 INFO ui.JettyUtils: Adding filter: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
16/03/19 05:59:35 WARN cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster has disassociated: 192.168.111.203:46505
16/03/19 05:59:35 WARN remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkYarnAM@192.168.111.203:46505] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Disassociated] 
16/03/19 05:59:35 WARN cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster has disassociated: 192.168.111.203:46505
16/03/19 05:59:35 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1458334003417_0002 (state: RUNNING)
16/03/19 05:59:35 INFO yarn.Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: 192.168.111.203
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
     queue: default
     start time: 1458334765746
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1458334003417_0002/
     user: root
16/03/19 05:59:35 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Application application_1458334003417_0002 has started running.
16/03/19 05:59:36 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 42938.
16/03/19 05:59:36 INFO netty.NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 42938
16/03/19 05:59:36 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
16/03/19 05:59:36 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.111.201:42938 with 534.5 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.111.201, 42938)
16/03/19 05:59:36 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
16/03/19 05:59:40 INFO cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster registered as AkkaRpcEndpointRef(Actor[akka.tcp://sparkYarnAM@192.168.111.203:34633/user/YarnAM#-40449267])
16/03/19 05:59:40 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Add WebUI Filter. org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter, Map(PROXY_HOSTS -> master, PROXY_URI_BASES -> http://master:8088/proxy/application_1458334003417_0002), /proxy/application_1458334003417_0002
16/03/19 05:59:40 INFO ui.JettyUtils: Adding filter: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
16/03/19 05:59:41 WARN cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster has disassociated: 192.168.111.203:34633
16/03/19 05:59:41 WARN cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster has disassociated: 192.168.111.203:34633
16/03/19 05:59:41 WARN remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkYarnAM@192.168.111.203:34633] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Disassociated] 
16/03/19 05:59:41 ERROR cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Yarn application has already exited with state FINISHED!
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/metrics/json,null}
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage/kill,null}
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/api,null}
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/static,null}
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/threadDump/json,null}
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/threadDump,null}
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/json,null}
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors,null}
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/environment/json,null}
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/environment,null}
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/rdd/json,null}
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/rdd,null}
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/json,null}
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage,null}
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/pool/json,null}
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/pool,null}
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage/json,null}
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage,null}
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/json,null}
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages,null}
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/job/json,null}
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/job,null}
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/json,null}
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs,null}
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO ui.SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.111.201:4040
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Stopping DAGScheduler
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Asking each executor to shut down
16/03/19 05:59:41 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Stopped
16/03/19 05:59:42 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
16/03/19 05:59:42 INFO storage.MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
16/03/19 05:59:42 INFO storage.BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
16/03/19 05:59:42 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
16/03/19 05:59:42 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
16/03/19 05:59:42 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
16/03/19 05:59:42 INFO spark.SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
16/03/19 05:59:42 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remoting shut down.
16/03/19 05:59:49 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after waiting maxRegisteredResourcesWaitingTime: 30000(ms)
16/03/19 05:59:49 INFO repl.SparkILoop: Created spark context..
Spark context available as sc.
16/03/19 05:59:49 INFO hive.HiveContext: Initializing execution hive, version 1.2.1
16/03/19 05:59:49 INFO client.ClientWrapper: Inspected Hadoop version: 2.6.0
16/03/19 05:59:49 INFO client.ClientWrapper: Loaded org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.Hadoop23Shims for Hadoop version 2.6.0
16/03/19 05:59:50 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
16/03/19 05:59:50 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
16/03/19 05:59:50 INFO DataNucleus.Persistence: Property hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown unknown - will be ignored
16/03/19 05:59:50 INFO DataNucleus.Persistence: Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
16/03/19 05:59:50 WARN DataNucleus.Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
16/03/19 05:59:51 WARN DataNucleus.Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
16/03/19 05:59:53 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: Setting MetaStore object pin classes with hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes="Table,StorageDescriptor,SerDeInfo,Partition,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order"
16/03/19 05:59:54 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
16/03/19 05:59:54 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
16/03/19 05:59:56 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
16/03/19 05:59:56 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
16/03/19 05:59:56 INFO metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql: Using direct SQL, underlying DB is DERBY
16/03/19 05:59:56 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: Initialized ObjectStore
16/03/19 05:59:57 WARN metastore.ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.2.0
16/03/19 05:59:57 WARN metastore.ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
16/03/19 05:59:57 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: Added admin role in metastore
16/03/19 05:59:57 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: Added public role in metastore
16/03/19 05:59:58 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: No user is added in admin role, since config is empty
16/03/19 05:59:58 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: get_all_databases
16/03/19 05:59:58 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=root    ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_all_databases   
16/03/19 05:59:58 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: get_functions: db=default pat=*
16/03/19 05:59:58 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=root    ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_functions: db=default pat=* 
16/03/19 05:59:58 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MResourceUri" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
16/03/19 05:59:58 INFO session.SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/root
16/03/19 05:59:58 INFO session.SessionState: Created local directory: /tmp/root
16/03/19 05:59:58 INFO session.SessionState: Created local directory: /tmp/e16dc45f-de41-4e69-9f73-c976cc3358c9_resources
16/03/19 05:59:58 INFO session.SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/root/e16dc45f-de41-4e69-9f73-c976cc3358c9
16/03/19 05:59:58 INFO session.SessionState: Created local directory: /tmp/root/e16dc45f-de41-4e69-9f73-c976cc3358c9
16/03/19 05:59:58 INFO session.SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/root/e16dc45f-de41-4e69-9f73-c976cc3358c9/_tmp_space.db
16/03/19 05:59:58 INFO hive.HiveContext: default warehouse location is /user/hive/warehouse
16/03/19 05:59:58 INFO hive.HiveContext: Initializing HiveMetastoreConnection version 1.2.1 using Spark classes.
16/03/19 05:59:58 INFO client.ClientWrapper: Inspected Hadoop version: 2.6.0
16/03/19 05:59:59 INFO client.ClientWrapper: Loaded org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.Hadoop23Shims for Hadoop version 2.6.0
16/03/19 06:00:00 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/03/19 06:00:00 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
16/03/19 06:00:00 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
16/03/19 06:00:00 INFO DataNucleus.Persistence: Property hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown unknown - will be ignored
16/03/19 06:00:00 INFO DataNucleus.Persistence: Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
16/03/19 06:00:00 WARN DataNucleus.Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
16/03/19 06:00:00 WARN DataNucleus.Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
16/03/19 06:00:01 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: Setting MetaStore object pin classes with hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes="Table,StorageDescriptor,SerDeInfo,Partition,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order"
16/03/19 06:00:02 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
16/03/19 06:00:02 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
16/03/19 06:00:04 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
16/03/19 06:00:04 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
16/03/19 06:00:04 INFO metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql: Using direct SQL, underlying DB is DERBY
16/03/19 06:00:04 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: Initialized ObjectStore
16/03/19 06:00:04 WARN metastore.ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.2.0
16/03/19 06:00:05 WARN metastore.ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
16/03/19 06:00:05 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: Added admin role in metastore
16/03/19 06:00:05 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: Added public role in metastore
16/03/19 06:00:05 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: No user is added in admin role, since config is empty
16/03/19 06:00:05 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: get_all_databases
16/03/19 06:00:05 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=root    ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_all_databases   
16/03/19 06:00:06 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: get_functions: db=default pat=*
16/03/19 06:00:06 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=root    ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_functions: db=default pat=* 
16/03/19 06:00:06 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MResourceUri" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
16/03/19 06:00:06 INFO session.SessionState: Created local directory: /tmp/b046e212-ccbd-4415-aec3-5b207f147fda_resources
16/03/19 06:00:06 INFO session.SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/root/b046e212-ccbd-4415-aec3-5b207f147fda
16/03/19 06:00:06 INFO session.SessionState: Created local directory: /tmp/root/b046e212-ccbd-4415-aec3-5b207f147fda
16/03/19 06:00:06 INFO session.SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/root/b046e212-ccbd-4415-aec3-5b207f147fda/_tmp_space.db
16/03/19 06:00:06 INFO repl.SparkILoop: Created sql context (with Hive support)..
SQL context available as sqlContext.

scala> val lines = sc.textFile("hdfs:///input")
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$assertNotStopped(SparkContext.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.defaultParallelism(SparkContext.scala:2063)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.defaultMinPartitions(SparkContext.scala:2076)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.textFile$default$2(SparkContext.scala:825)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:21)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:26)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:28)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:30)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:32)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:34)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:36)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:38)
    at <init>(<console>:40)
    at .<init>(<console>:44)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1340)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:674)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your YARN application exits immediately after it starts:

```
16/03/19 05:59:41 WARN cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster has disassociated: 192.168.111.203:34633
16/03/19 05:59:41 WARN cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster has disassociated: 192.168.111.203:34633
16/03/19 05:59:41 WARN remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkYarnAM@192.168.111.203:34633] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Disassociated] 
16/03/19 05:59:41 ERROR cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Yarn application has already exited with state FINISHED!
```

Then, SparkContext is closed, so any action on this context will throw the exception you see.

Check the "Application Master" logs (visible through YARN's UI) to see the cause for the failure. This could be a memory configuration issue, network issues (e.g. host unreachable) and more - the log on the driver side (which is what you pasted) won't tell you which one it is.

Answer (score 11):

I encountered this in my Spark Structured Streaming application when I forgot to include the following:

```
spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```